# issue in redirect urls in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to redirect a url to another location using htaccess file. Here's what I write but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?module=paper&func=view_abtract&code=([0-9]+) http://$1.papers.abstract.com [L,R=301]
```

I try to find the problem ... but nothing found

Edited.

Comment: Do you have mod rewrite installed and enabled? Assuming it is installed add this above the rewrite rule RewriteEngine on

Comment: yes,I have some other rules in htaccess and they work well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Query string in RewriteRule. Use this code instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^module=paper&func=view_astract&code=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ http://%1.papers.abstract.com? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: But I think what you write will redirect all the index.php?**** .I just need to redirect index.php?module=paper&.... not others like index.php?module=users....

Comment: No - *both* the `RewriteCond` and the `RewriteRule` conditions must be true for the rewrite to go ahead, so the former checks the query string and the latter checks the URL.

Comment: sorry i was wrongaout your answer,I checked it but it redirect to that query string at the new url,I mean it take me to : http://papers.abstract.com/?module=paper&func=view_astract&code=XX .I

Comment: Then you must explicitly put a null query string into the redirect: `http://papers.abstract.com?` (note the trailing question mark).

Comment: thank you for ? mark. What should I do if I want to redirect it to http://X.papers.abstract.com when X is taken from &code=  ??

Comment: Then you need to capture the code value in your RewriteCond: `^module=paper&func=view_astract&code=([^&]+)` and include it in the RewriteRule: `http://%1.papers.abstract.com`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Borodin for your meaningful discussion, (sorry I wasn't in front of my computer so could not respond earlier). I updated my answer based on these comments.